# What do I need to change in Xcode or in my Developer profile in order to get rid of the error in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I don't understand why Xcode thinks I need to create a unique identifier for the project/app (it's just a simple sticker pack), when it shows on my Developer profile that I already own the Bundle ID and am able to use it in my apps. Can someone please help me understand this?

[image]
[image]

UPDATE:

Just wanted to provide more context with pictures. As you can see, the info in Xcode matches up with the info online and in my Developer cert. So again, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here.

[image: DeveloperCert]

[image: Developer ID in Xcode]

[image: The Errors I get in Xcode]

[image: App ID as seen in xcode]

[image]

UPDATE #2:

It was suggested to me to change the Product Bundle Identifier in Build Settings to something unique. However, since I've already registered the app in my online developer account, doesn't that mean that my identifier is in fact unique? I don't think Apple would allow me to register with an ID that wasn't unique would it? Anyway, here's a screenshot of what I had already done, but was suggested to me to do in order to try and fix my problem. The problem still exists, so I don't think changing the product bundle ID is going to solve it.

[image: Product Bundle ID in Build Settings]

Answer (score 0):

This is the error message when your Package bundle is not unique. When you try to manage automatic signing in XCode for iOS automation, all package bundle should have unique ID.

To solve this, please find below steps:

- Navigate to ‘Build Settings’ tab.
- Click on product bundle identifier to display in Edit mode.
- Update it to ‘com.test.abc’.
- Navigate back to ‘General’ tab.
- ‘Automatic’ manage signing should be created.

Worked for me! Hope it helps!

 Source: https://club.ministryoftesting.com/t/failed-to-create-provisioning-profile-error-is-displayed-on-automatic-manage-signing-for-ios-app-automation/14814

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. However, I think I might have already tried to do what you suggested. If you have the time, would you please look at the screenshots I put under "UPDATE:" above? I have better documentation now than my initial question. Thank you so much for your help! I truly appreciate it.